# FFmpeg return 'invalid argument' only for some runs, even though it is the same code

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I have code in Python where I need to use FFmpeg to merge an audio and a video downloaded using pytube together:

```
for video in p.videos:
    video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4',resolution='480p')[0].download(parent_dir+'/mp4/processing/video')
    print(video.streams.filter(only_audio=True)[1].download(parent_dir+'/mp4/processing/audio'))

    subprocess.run([

        r'c:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg', '-i',
        os.path.join(parent_dir+'/mp4/processing/video',video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4',resolution='480p')[0].default_filename)
        ,'-i',
        os.path.join(parent_dir+'/mp4/processing/audio',video.streams.filter(only_audio=True)[1].default_filename),
        '-c:v','copy','-c:a','copy',
        os.path.join(parent_dir+'/mp4',video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4',resolution='480p')[0].title+'.mp4')

    ])
```

I thought the code was working perfectly, but in some cases, the FFmpeg returns "invalid argument", like this example:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/videos/mp4/processing/video\Dropkick Murphys - Rose Tattoo (Video).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-04-04T10:16:52.000000Z
  Duration: 00:05:26.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 557 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 7 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-04T10:16:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/videos/mp4/processing/audio\Dropkick Murphys - Rose Tattoo (Video).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-04-04T10:16:00.000000Z
  Duration: 00:05:26.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 3 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-04T10:16:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
D:/videos/mp4\Dropkick Murphys - "Rose Tattoo" (Video).mp4: Invalid argument
```

For some reason, the FFmpeg say that my output name is invalid, but I don't understand why, given that I ran the code multiple times before and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was messing up my code, it was the `""` around the name of the video title. I solved it quickly by adding `.replace('"','')` before the title of the video and it worked fine!